# Switching camera angle based on several images

Tags: image-processing, 3d, reference-implementation, image-restoration

Given a number (3 or 4) of different images of a given subject from different angles, how do I interpolate to an angle that isn't available on any of the photos?

What is this technique called and is there any software that does this available? (Preferably Open Source.)

Comment: Virtual viewpoint generation : https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Carreira_Virtual_View_Networks_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf

http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/3140000/3130855/a235-penner.pdf?ip=89.204.135.115&id=3130855&acc=OA&key=4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E5945DC2EABF3343C&__acm__=1550525956_cf9b06eba0ff135ddc89ade725343843

Comment: @TolgaBirdal Short answers are still answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

- [Virtual View Networks for Object Reconstruction](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Carreira_Virtual_View_Networks_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf).
- [Soft 3D Reconstruction for View Synthesis](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3130800.3130855).

**Remark**: Created an answer from [Tolga Birdal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/7338/tolga-birdal)'s comment.